# Use mod_macro with environment variable

Tags: apache, apache2, environment-variables, virtualhost

Is it possible to use a macro with the value of a environment variable?

E.g.

```
<Macro setLog $name>
  CustomLog "|cronolog -l /var/www/logs/$name/access.log /var/www/logs/$name/%Y-%m-%d_access.log" logging
  ErrorLog "|cronolog -l /var/www/logs/$name/error.log /var/www/logs/$name/%Y-%m-%d_error.log"
</Macro>

SetEnvIf Host soup* path=soup

use setLog path
```

Which would 'print' the macro with `path`. Can I use the value for path? (in this case `soup`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the internal variables modified by SetEnv and SetEnvIf are during request processing. Your macros are expanded when the configuration is parsed -- the logs are also opened up front and can't depend on parameters of the request.

Comment: As a clarification to the ambiguous term "*environment variable*" in the question's current version ("*Is it possible to use a macro with the value of a **environment variable**?*"): *Operating system process* environment variables, such as *Debian Apache*'s `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}`, can be used in *mod_macro* macros. ( https://salsa.debian.org/apache-team/apache2/-/blob/debian/2.4.56-1_deb11u2/debian/config-dir/envvars#L23 ... https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html )